# Undefined returned from recursive function

Tags: javascript

I have the following functions defined in JavaScript:

```
        function rfactorial(n, f) {
            if (n == 0) {
                return f;
            }
            rfactorial(n-1, f*n);
        }

        function dofactorial(){
            var n = prompt("Enter number");
            var f = rfactorial(parseInt(n), 1);
            alert("Factorial = " + f);

            if (confirm("Do another one?")) {
                dofactorial();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that in `dofactorial()`, `f` is `undefined`. This is strange since if I check the value of `f` in `rfactorial()` it is correctly calculated right before the `return`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: return rfactorial(n-1, f*n);

Comment: Did you perhaps forget the `return` at the `rfactorial(n-1, f*n);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function rfactorial(n, f) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return f;
        }
       return rfactorial(n-1, f*n);
    }

    function dofactorial(){
        var n = prompt("Enter number");
        var f = rfactorial(parseInt(n), 1);
        alert("Factorial = " + f);

        if (confirm("Do another one?")) {
            dofactorial();
        }
    }

    dofactorial()
```

Note    return rfactorial(n-1, f*n);
You forget return

Comment: Oh my, how couldn't have I notice that...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code to this:

```
01| function rfactorial(n, f) {
02|    if (n == 0) {
03|       return f;
04|    }
05|    return new rfactorial(n-1, f*n);
06| }
07| function dofactorial(){
08|    var n = prompt("Enter number");
09|    var f = rfactorial(parseInt(n), 1);
10|   alert("Factorial = " + f);
11|    if (confirm("Do another one?")) {
12|    dofactorial();
13|   }
14| }
```

On line 3 you have 2 options `return new rfactorial(n-1, f*n);`, or `return new rfactorial(n-1, f*n);`. Both work.

Answer (score 0):

The point is you forgot to write return before calling the function recursively

To call a function recursively it's needed to assign it's value to some variable or some parameter (it's depends on the logic). In your case you are calling `rfactorial()` but when it's comes in a part of recursive call it's not returning value. So you have to put return over there.

```
function rfactorial(n, f) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return f;
        }
       return rfactorial(n-1, f*n);  // here you forgot to include return keyword
    }

    function dofactorial(){
        var n = prompt("Enter number");
        var f = rfactorial(parseInt(n), 1);
        alert("Factorial = " + f);

        if (confirm("Do another one?")) {
            dofactorial();
        }
    }

    dofactorial();
```

Here is working [FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/ea5UB/)